# VC dimension of signed intervals

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension

*Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms*, 
Section 6.8, Question 9 is

> Let $\mathcal H$ be the class of signed intervals, that is, $\mathcal H = \{ h_{a,b,s} : a \le b, s \in \{-1, 1\} \}$ where
>   $$ h_{a,b,s} = \begin{cases}
> s & \text{if } x \in [a, b] \\
> -s & \text{if } x \notin [a, b]
> \end{cases}
> .$$
>   Calculate $\operatorname{VCdim}(\mathcal H)$.

My understanding is that it should be 2, since we cannot label this as (1 -1 1) for instance. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you say more about what you have in mind here? I doubt this can get an answer right now. In particular, you have "unsigned" in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be 3.
VCDim(H)$\geq$3 because any labelling (even of the form (1,-1,1)) is realisable by H. Just consider $h_{b,b,-1}$, where b is the middle point of your chosen subset. On the other hand, VCDim(H)<4 because the labelling of (1,-1,1,-1) is not realisable by any function in H.

Answer (score 1):

If for example $C = \{c_1, c_2, c_3\}$ and assuming WLOG that $c_1 \leq c_2 \leq c_3$ then we can have for $s = 1$ every label except $(1, -1, 1)$ but that label is obtained when we "switch" to $s = -1$ then for $|C| = 3$, $H$ shatters $C$. Now for $|C| = 4$ ($C = \{c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4\}$ and $c_1 \leq c_2 \leq c_3 \leq c_4$ WLOG) it is not possible to get the label $(1, -1, 1, -1)$ since if $c_3 > b$ then $c_4 > b$ by assumption and we fail to get the label above. The same holds for $c_2 < a$ (and in turn $c_1 < a$). So the VC dimension of $H$ is $3$.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can have the label $(1,-1,1)$ --- and any other label in $\{0,1\}^3$ for that matter --- for a set $C\subset \mathbb{R}$ with $|C| = 3$, through an appropriate choice of the parameters $a$, $b$ and, in particular, $s$. Therefore, you can establish that $\textrm{VCdim}(\mathcal{H})\geq 3$. Can you do the same for a set $C\subset\mathbb{R}$ with $|C| = 4$?